# No argument works witch the command check_drivesize

Tags: nrpe, nsclient++, centreon

I querry a Windows Server where NSClient++ is installed with NRPE.
The matter is I can't pass any filter/argument with the command check_drivesize !

This is the command :

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_centreon_nrpe3 -H x.x.x.x -n -c check_drivesize "crit=free<10%" drive=c: -2
```

The result :

```
CRITICAL F:\: 270.247GB/299.872GB used|'D:\ used'=18.42258GB;63.89843;71.88573;0;79.87304 'D:\ used %'=23%;80;90;0;100 'E:\ used'=37.57743GB;79.89843;89.88573;0;99.87303 'E:\ used %'=38%;80;90;0;100 'F:\ used'=270.24709GB;239.89765;269.88486;0;299.87206 'F:\ used %'=90%;80;90;0;100 'C:\ used'=38.88769GB;63.72421;71.68974;0;79.65527 'C:\ used %'=49%;80;90;0;100
```

I did a lots of tests, and whatever the argument/filter, it always returned the same thing.

Here you can find the nsclient.ini

```
; in flight - TODO
[/settings/default]

; Undocumented key
password = ************

; Undocumented key
allowed hosts = **********

; in flight - TODO

[/settings/NRPE/server]
; Undocumented key
ssl options = no-sslv2,no-sslv3
use ssl = false
allow arguments = true
allow nasty characters = true

; Undocumented key
verify mode = peer-cert

; Undocumented key
insecure = true

; # DH KEY
dh = ${certificate-path}/nrpe_dh_2048.pem

; in flight - TODO
[/modules]

; Undocumented key
CheckExternalScripts = enabled

; Undocumented key
CheckHelpers = enabled

; Undocumented key
CheckEventLog = enabled

; Undocumented key
CheckNSCP = enabled

; Undocumented key
CheckDisk = enabled

; Undocumented key
CheckSystem = enabled

; Undocumented key
NSClientServer = enabled

; Undocumented key
NRPEServer = enabled
```

Why does the command keep the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

the parameters/arguments must be given using `-a` on the command line. you may also need to quote the drive argument and put `-2` before the arguments

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_centreon_nrpe3 -H x.x.x.x -n -2 -c check_drivesize -a "critical=free<10%" "drive=c:"
```

look at `check_centreon_nrpe3 --help` for more parameters.

as with your syntax you send no arguments to `check_drivesize`, its runs with its default configuration: check all drives with `"warning=used>80%"` and `"critical=used>90%"`.

as your drive `F:` has a bit more than 90% used, the whole test returns `critical`